# Global Database on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am busy with the deployment of an architecture in which I got stuck in between with the idea of implementing certain things.
Can anybody advice what to do in the following case :-

1. I have 8 worldwide locations lets say Paris , New york , China , India etc.. At Each locations I have some local Database which I call it as production database (lets say it is sensitive). Now , I need to make a EC2 instance in my AWS Account and I want to make this EC2 instance as a Globally centralized database so that It is always in synced to all the 8 locations and It gets update whatever the changes are implementing in all the 8 location's database.
   All the 8 locations database are physical servers in their databases.

Please help/advice me with the solution of above question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to advice you, i need to understand the purpose of the globally centralised DB: DR? Backup? BI(Reporting based on consolidated data)?

In case it is DR: You can sync the DB of each location based on the underlying technology to a separate schema under the globally centralized DB.

In case it is BI: Maybe you can consider another way of doing that, like Kinesis-Redshift-Mapreduce?

If you can provide me more information, i can consult you more...

Comment: I just need the Globally Centralized Database for Database replication and also I need to make a Global Filesystem on another EC2 (synchronised to all the file servers in 8 locations) and by this it should be able to transfer the (lets say 8-10 gb of file with the thought of incrementals backups).
Let me know if you need it to be more precisely.

Comment: What is the main purpose of doing that? I need this info, to advice you in an open-minded way...

Comment: The Main purpose is Auto-Replication between the 8 locations and a global one.
I just need to replicate the database from 7 locations to a global accessible system.

Comment: If it is just DB, then it is much more simpler than DR, then use the related DB replication tools and that's enough?